# Why does my Feynman diagram get distorted?

Tags: tikz-feynman

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,aps,floatfix,twocolumn]{revtex4}
%\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal= a to be] 
{ i1 -- [scalar] a[dot] -- [scalar] i2, 
a -- [photon, half left] b, 
b --[photon, half left] a, 
f1 -- [scalar] b -- [scalar] f2, };

\end{document}
```

I tried the above code under TikZ.

However, the diagram I get looks like the rightmost diagram.....[image]

I cannot understand why the diagram looks so weird.....Maybe because I am writing on the paper on two columns....

I tried everything but the diagram wouldn't change and it is extremely frustrating...

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you add a minimal compilable code which gives the distorted diagram?

Comment: Yes I edited the question. Could you please help me?

Comment: Why do you say the diagram is weird? What should be the correct figure?

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`? Unless you're using `lualatex`, the advanced positioning algorithms are not used.

Answer (score 0):

What @Torbjorn said.

> Are you using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`? Unless you're using `lualatex`, the
> advanced positioning algorithms are not used

I.e., you need to use `lualatex`.

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `lualatex` and *not*. `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,aps,floatfix,twocolumn]{revtex4}
%\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{feynmf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{theoremref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    
    \feynmandiagram [horizontal= a to be] 
    { i1 -- [scalar] a[dot] -- [scalar] i2, 
        a -- [photon, half left] b, 
        b --[photon, half left] a, 
        f1 -- [scalar] b -- [scalar] f2, };
    
\end{document}
```

Then you'll get:

[image]